# CEFSharp browser status in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

I am trying to get the cefbrowser to show browser status for example like vb.net web browser you can call `Label1.Text = WebBrowser1.StatusText.ToString` to receive the loading URL and when mousing over links/hyperlinks will show the URL path.
any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

In cefsharp you can use the ChromiumWebBrowser.StatusMessage event to get this information.

Have a look in the [documentation](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_StatusMessage.htm) ;-)